# Draw a square base pyramid easily modifiable

Tags: tikz-pgf

As part of a projet, I want to:

- draw a square pyramid easily modifiable by the variable "width", "height" and "depth", a bit like cuboïd creation.
- draw the back line densely dashed

*i | The tip of the pyramid should be centered*

I've already done this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  %\tikzset{%
  %}
  pyramidoid/.pic={
    \draw [ 
    style={pic actions, solid, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) -- ++(-\pyrscale*\pyrx,0,0) coordinate (a) edge coordinate [pos=1] (d) ++(0,0,-\pyrscale*\pyrz) -- ++(0,\pyrscale*\pyrz,0) coordinate (b) -- cycle
    (o) -- (0, 0, -\pyrscale*\pyrz) coordinate (c) edge (d) -- (b) edge (d) -- cycle
    ;
  },
  width/.store in=\pyrx,
  height/.store in=\pyry,
  depth/.store in=\pyrz,
  units/.store in=\pyrunits,
  scale/.store in=\pyrscale,
  width=10,
  height=10,
  depth=10,
  units=cm,
  scale=.2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  %\pic {pyramidoid};
  \pic {pyramidoid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};%      Pyramide en PC (perspective cavalière)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But i don't know if it's the proper approach, having recently started to learn LaTex...

Example of cuboid diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  annotated cuboid/.pic={
    \tikzset{%
      every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
      /cuboid/.cd,
      #1
    }
    \draw [every edge/.append style={pic actions, densely dashed, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e) edge (g) -- (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- (a) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f) edge (g) -- (d) -- cycle;
    ;
  },
  /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
  /cuboid/.cd,
  width/.store in=\cubex,
  height/.store in=\cubey,
  depth/.store in=\cubez,
  units/.store in=\cubeunits,
  scale/.store in=\cubescale,
  width=10,
  height=10,
  depth=10,
  units=cm,
  scale=.2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \pic {annotated cuboid};%      cube en PC (perspective cavalière)
  %\pic {annotated cuboid={width=20, height=5, depth=10}};
  %\pic {annotated cuboid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a pyramid with a square base that has 2 faces perpendicular to the base?

Comment: The dashed lines will need a separate \draw.  Personally, I would have use a macro and passed the width, height and depth as arguments.  Then again, I am also fond of PGF basic layer commands.

Comment: The tip of the pyramid should be centered. I saw cuboid code (cf. example just above) where only one draw function was needed. I don't know if it's possible in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This draws a pyramid in the "oblique projection", thank you so much for the translation! Your approach is overall great but I'd use the pgf keys slightly differently for the sake of name space, and also store them under a `pyramidoid`, say, directory.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/pyramidoid/.style={code={
    \tikzset{pyramidoid/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pyramidoid/##1}}
    \draw [solid, opacity=.5, pic actions]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) 
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},0,0) coordinate (a)
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},\pv{scale}*\pv{depth},0) coordinate (b) 
    (0,\pv{scale}*\pv{depth},0) coordinate (c) 
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width}/2,\pv{scale}*\pv{depth}/2,\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (d) 
     (b) edge[densely dashed] (a)
     edge[densely dashed] (c) edge[densely dashed] (d)
     (o) -- (a) -- (d) -- (o) -- (c) -- (d) ;
  }},
  pyramidoid/.cd,
  width/.initial=10,
  height/.initial=5,
  depth/.initial=10,
  scale/.initial=.2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(30:1cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},line cap=round,line join=round]
  \pic {pyramidoid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};%      Pyramide en PC (perspective cavalière)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you ever want to switch to arguably more realistic projections, you may use the following code, which draws the pyramid but you can change the perspective as described in section **64 Three Point Perspective Drawing Library** of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\tikzset{pics/pyramidoid/.style={code={
    \tikzset{pyramidoid/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pyramidoid/##1}}
    \draw [solid, opacity=.5, pic actions]
    (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0) coordinate (o) 
    (tpp cs:x=-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},y=0,z=0) coordinate (a)
    (tpp cs:x=-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},y=\pv{scale}*\pv{depth},z=0) coordinate (b) 
    (tpp cs:x=0,y=\pv{scale}*\pv{depth},z=0) coordinate (c) 
    (tpp cs:x=-\pv{scale}*\pv{width}/2,y=\pv{scale}*\pv{depth}/2,z=\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (d) 
    (o) edge[densely dashed] (c)
    (c) edge[densely dashed] (b) edge[densely dashed] (d)
    (o) -- (a) -- (b) -- (d) -- (a) (o) edge (d);
  }},
  pyramidoid/.cd,
  width/.initial=10,
  height/.initial=5,
  depth/.initial=10,
  scale/.initial=.2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view,line cap=round,line join=round,perspective]
  \pic {pyramidoid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};%      Pyramide en PC (perspective cavalière)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then using e.g.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view,line cap=round,line join=round,perspective={
    q = {(0,5,0)}}]
  \pic {pyramidoid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};%      Pyramide en PC (perspective cavalière)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

And if you drop the `perspective` key,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view,line cap=round,line join=round]
  \pic {pyramidoid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};%      Pyramide en PC (perspective cavalière)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: "perspective cavalière" is the French name of "Oblique projection". the object are not really in perspective. It's useful when teaching geometry to preserve parallelism.

Comment: thanks for your post, it allows me to understand some specific information. I'm still struggling to understand everything because there is a lot of information to digest.

Comment: @Nilcouv Thank you so much for explaining `perspective cavalière`! I added some code for this projection as well. If you tell me what specifically you are struggling with, I may be able to help.

Comment: I've got difficulties to understand the use of "pv". I saw you declare it with "`\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pyramidoid/##1}}`", then use it to manipulate variables such as "(tpp cs:x=-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},y=0,z=0) coordinate (a)".
there is also "tpp cs:" that you use to declare the coordinate of your point, such as "(tpp cs:x=-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},y=0,z=0) coordinate (a)".
Are there anywhere a command dictonnary on internet ?

Comment: something seemed like off, and it takes me and my colleague some time to undestand what was is. if the base is a square, it doesn't look like it. I'm currently searching the solution, so if you have it, i'm open to it.

Comment: I find the following trick "\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(2cm,0cm)},y={(25:1cm)},z={(0cm,2cm)}". I don't know if there is a more elegant way...