# how to render figures in oblique projection with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to render the following figure with an oblique projection to preserve the initial form of the triangular base.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/prismoid/.style={code={
    \tikzset{prismoid/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/prismoid/##1}}
    \draw [solid, opacity=.5, pic actions]
    %%  point o - avant droit
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o)
    %% point a - avant gauche
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},0,0) coordinate (a)
    %% point b - arrière central
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width}/2,\pv{scale}*\pv{depth},0) coordinate (b)
    %% point c - haut avant droit
    (0,0,\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (c)
    %% point d - haut avant gauche
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width},0,\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (d)
    %% point e - haut arrière central
    (-\pv{scale}*\pv{width}/2,\pv{scale}*\pv{depth},\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (e)
    %% jonction entre les points
     %(b) edge[densely dashed] (a)
     %edge[densely dashed] (c) edge[densely dashed] (d)
     (o) -- (a) -- (d) -- (c)  -- (o)
     (c) -- (e) -- (d)
     (b) edge[densely dashed] (o) edge[densely dashed] (a) edge[densely dashed] (e)
     ;
  }},
  prismoid/.cd,
  width/.initial=10,
  height/.initial=10,
  depth/.initial=10,
  scale/.initial=.2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(2cm,0cm)},y={(45:1cm)},z={(0cm,2cm)},line cap=round,line join=round]
  \pic {prismoid={width=10, height=10, depth=10}};
  %\pic {prismoid={width=20, height=10, depth=10}};
  %\pic {prismoid={width=10, height=20, depth=10}};
  %\pic {prismoid={width=10, height=10, depth=20}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code is from @Schrödinger's cat, who helps me out in [my previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528444/draw-a-square-base-pyramid-easily-modifiable). I already tried to change the value of `\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(2cm,0cm)},y={(45:1cm)},z={(0cm,2cm)}`, or change it by other optional arguments (3d view, perspective) but it doesn't work. I'm currently searching on internet, but if someone has any idea, I'm opened to any suggestion.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you want to achieve. You draw the triangle in the xy plane, and define `x={(2cm,0cm)},y={(45:1cm)}`, so of course the triangle gets "deformed". But this is what projections do. What should the projection you are after do specifically?

Comment: I think my demand is impossible.I would like to preserve the form of the triangle with the same point of view but it doesn't seem possible. The best trick is just to rotate the figure to show the base

Comment: No, this can be done in multiple ways, but as you request an adaptation of an existing code. Its author is best able to do it.

Comment: I'd like to allow the student to be able to recognize the form of the prism base. So if the square is an equilateral triangle, or a square, the student is able to quickly identify the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cavalier perspective (in french) retains the parallelism. To make such a perspective, it is enough to reproduce the front side identically at a vanishing angle to obtain the rear side. This can be done with TikZ in the same way as if one were to make this construction with a ruler, compass and square in the traditional way.

Here, I used the `calc` library which allows you to add coordinates (a coordinate is thus seen as a vector). By adding to each vertex of the front face the same vector, we obtain the vertices of the back face.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% front face
\coordinate (A) at (-1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,2);
\coordinate (C) at (1,0);
% vector v defines the leakage angle
\coordinate (v) at (.8,.8);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
% back face
\coordinate (A') at ($(A)+(v)$);
\coordinate (B') at ($(B)+(v)$);
\coordinate (C') at ($(C)+(v)$);
\draw[dashed] (C')--(A')--(B');
\draw (B')--(C');
\draw[dashed](A)--(A');
\draw(B)--(B');
\draw(C)--(C');
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. Yeah I think my approach was just wrong. I have to draw the figure depending what I want to show.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do all the time, I have drawn countless figures for my students and all of them as if I had built them the old-fashioned way (ruler, square and compass). I adopted LaTeX for this purpose because the figures are even more precisely constructed than when I used Indian ink.